# Java: Filling two-dimensional array from input file

Tags: java

Basically, I need to scan this (from an input .txt file):

```
oooooooo
#S#ooooo
oo#oo##o
ooo#ooo#
oo#oo$oo
o######o
oooooooo
```

Into a two-dimensional array.  Here's what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("inputFile.txt"));
    numRows = scan.nextInt();
    numColumns = scan.nextInt();
    mazeArray = new char[numRows][numColumns];


    for(int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
    {
        strings = scan.next();

        for(int column = 0; column < numColumns; column++)
        {
            mazeArray[row][column] = strings.charAt(row);
            System.out.print(mazeArray[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

The output is all wrong:

```
oooooooo
SSSSSSSS
########
########
oooooooo
########
oooooooo
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// Change row -> column

mazeArray[row][column] = strings.charAt(column);
```

Comment: Well, that fixed it, it's outputting correctly now.  Something so simple was giving me so much trouble.  :/  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` will always print a new line. Instead you should use `System.out.print()` and print out a line break "\n" after each row.

Try this:

```
for(int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
{
    strings = scan.next();
    for(int column = 0; column < numColumns; column++)
    {
        mazeArray[row][column] = strings.charAt(row);
        System.out.print(mazeArray[row][column]);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

Comment: That didn't help, but it made me realize that the output was completely wrong to begin with.

Comment: This is my output (but with each character on a new line, not all on one line):

o
o
o
o
o
o
o
o
S
S
S
S
S
S
S
S
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
o
o
o
o
o
o
o
o
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
#
o
o
o
o
o
o
o
o

I'll edit the main question with the output